# Vue.js precise CSS class toggling for CSS animation retriggering

Tags: vue.js, css-animations

I'm facing a problem with Vue.js where `nextTick()` doesn't seem to be working as expected.

I have the following HTML code

```
<q-icon
  color='grey-7'
  :name="connectionStateIcon"
  class="icon-reconnect"
  :class='[$storage.state.websocket.state, reconnect_pulse]'></q-icon>
```

where `connectionStateIcon` is a computed property which selects the icon of the current connection status, `$storage.state.websocket.state` holds the text representation of the current connection state (open, closed...) which is to be used to select a css definition (ie `.q-icon.icon-reconnect.open`) to apply a certain base color to the icon and `reconnect_pulse` is a `data` variable which is used to trigger the animation.

Whenever a new reconnect attempt got triggered, the animation should be run, and `reconnect_pulse` should transition from class `''` to `'reconnectpulse'` in order to trigger the animation.

```
data: function () {
  return {
    reconnect_pulse: '',
  }
},
created() {
  this.$eventbus.$on('connection-state', (state) => {
    if (state == 'reconnecting') {
      this.reconnect_pulse = ''; // remove the class `reconnectpulse`
      this.$nextTick(() => { this.reconnect_pulse = 'reconnectpulse'; }); // add the class `reconnectpulse` to trigger the animation
      //setTimeout(() => { this.reconnect_pulse = 'reconnectpulse'; }, 100) // this works, and more reliably, the bigger the timeout is.
    }
  })
},
```

The CSS is the following:

```
@keyframes reconnectpulse {
  from { color:#ffa000; } to { }    /* from orange to whichever base color the icon has */
}

.q-icon.reconnectpulse {
  animation: reconnectpulse 2.0s ease-in; /* the above animation's properties */
}

.q-icon.icon-reconnect { }  /* "grey-7" is default base color */

.q-icon.icon-reconnect.open {
  color: yellowgreen; /* when the connection is established, select green as the base color */
}
```

My issue is that I'm assuming that `this.$nextTick`'s code will be executed as soon as Vue has finished executing the current tick in which the CSS class `reconnectpulse` has been removed, so that in the next tick `reconnectpulse` can be applied again and the DOM would then trigger the animation.

But for some reason this only works once. If I replace `this.$nextTick` with `setTimeout` with a relatively large timeout, so that the element has the class `reconnectpulse` removed for a long enough time before it gets reapplied, then it works. With a timeout of 20ms it works sometimes, sometimes not, with 0ms only once (because the initial value of `reconnect_pulse` is `''`) with 100ms every time.

The very odd thing is that I'm currently rewriting the Vue component, and the old version has a `setTimeout` of 0ms, and it works every time. I don't know which exactly are the differences, as the old code is somewhat confusing, but in essence, the code regarding the animation is identical.

I was expecting `this.$nextTick` to be able to replace `setTimeout` in a very precise manner, but it does not work, and I don't feel good at manually adjusting `setTimeout`'s delay as this may vary between devices.

What is wrong with `this.$nextTick` in this scenario? What else can I do to archive the desired effect without using `setTimeout`?

---

The same applies when accessing the elements directly:

```
_.forEach(document.querySelectorAll('.icon-reconnect'), (icon) => {
  icon.classList.remove('reconnectpulse')
})
setTimeout(() => {
  _.forEach(document.querySelectorAll('.icon-reconnect'), (icon) => {
    icon.classList.add('reconnectpulse')
  })
}, 100)
```

where I then was expecting the following to work (but it did not):

```
_.forEach(document.querySelectorAll('.icon-reconnect'), (icon) => {
  icon.classList.remove('reconnectpulse')
  icon.classList.add('reconnectpulse')
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to not clear the class before reapplying it, but to replace it with another one which has identical animation properties.

```
<q-icon
  color='grey-7'
  :name="connectionStateIcon"
  class="icon-reconnect"
  :class='[$storage.state.websocket.state, reconnect_pulse]'></q-icon>
```

```
data: function () {
  return {
    reconnect_pulse: '',
  }
},
created() {
  this.$eventbus.$on('connection-state', (state) => {
    if (state == 'reconnecting') {
      if (this.reconnect_pulse != 'reconnect-pulse-tick') {
        this.reconnect_pulse = 'reconnect-pulse-tick'
      }
      else {
        this.reconnect_pulse = 'reconnect-pulse-tock'
      }
    }
  })
},
```

```
@keyframes reconnect-pulse-tick {
  from { color:#ffa000; } to { }
}
.q-icon.reconnect-pulse-tick {
  animation: reconnect-pulse-tick 2.0s ease-in;
}

@keyframes reconnect-pulse-tock {
  from { color:#ffa000; } to { }
}
.q-icon.reconnect-pulse-tock {
  animation: reconnect-pulse-tock 2.0s ease-in;
}

.q-icon.icon-reconnect { }  /* "grey-7" is default base color */

.q-icon.icon-reconnect.open {
  color: yellowgreen; /* when the connection is established, select green as the base color */
}
```

In this case it's important that the animation keyframes also have different names, as shown in the css code above.

TBH, I actually prefer this solution much more to the one which attempted to use `nextTick` or `setTimeout`.